# Resolution error of specific IP addersses

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp

I have a network with the following topology:

```
+-----------+       +-----------+
|192.168.1.1+---+--->192.168.1.7|
+-----------+   |   +-----------+
   server       |      windows
                |
                |   +-----------+
                +--->192.168.1.3|
                    +-----------+
                      GNU/Linux
```

`server` machine is connected to the internet and acts as a DHCP server for the local network. `GNU/Linux` machine works fine. `windows` machine, however, exhibits a strange behavior - it fails to resolve specific internet IP addresses.

I can ping most of the addresses from `windows` machine:

```
C:\Users\User>tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  x.x.x.x
  ....
  7     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```

But for some addresses `windows` machine routs to its local network address:

```
C:\Users\User>tracert 198.185.159.145

Tracing route to 198.185.159.145 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  WINDOWS.machine.example.com [192.168.1.7]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Same trace from the `GNU/Linux` machine looks like this:

```
traceroute to 198.185.159.145 (198.185.159.145), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.322 ms  0.288 ms  0.278 ms
....
14  * * *
15  198.185.159.145 (198.185.159.145)  158.510 ms  158.523 ms  158.505 ms
```

Windows firewall is turned off, `server` `iptables` chains are all set to `ACCEPT`.

What could cause this behavior?

#### edit 1

`windows` machine route tables:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7     10
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.0.0.0        224.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    266
  192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    266
  223.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    266
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    266
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  9    306 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  9    306 2001::/32                On-link
  9    306 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3c09:1c95:3f57:fef8/128
                On-link
  5    266 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    306 fe80::3c09:1c95:3f57:fef8/128
                On-link
  5    266 fe80::9ce4:a7a5:5ab:8512/128
                On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  5    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
```

Comment: You'll have to include the routing table from the Windows machine in your question. Otherwise there is not much chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Check the network mask on the Windows host.

Comment: @kasperd added routing table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad network mask (`224.0.0.0`) for your local network that covers the destination address, too.

Put in the correct network mask, and it should work.

Comment: I don't know much about windows networking. Where did this rule come from? Could it be a configuration of the DHCP server?

Comment: Is the Windows host actually configured to use DHCP, or is it manually configured? Someone may have also entered a `route` command. Someone certainly put in a route to the host address `223.255.255.255` to be on-link, and that is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: @Sergey If both machines are DHCP clients they are supposed to both be getting the mask from the DHCP server. That of course just prompts a new question. How is it possible for the two to get different masks. You can look at the routing table on the Linux machine for comparison as well as what it received through DHCP. On Linux I will usually use `ps -fC dhclient | cat` to find the name of the lease file and then `grep subnet-mask `<filename> to see what mask it received.

Comment: @kasperd I use network manager. Route is `inet4 192.168.1.3/24`. I recall that `windows` machine was previously located somewhere else. Probably got this route there...